# Converting parts of Strings to Character to be used in if/else statements

Tags: java

I'm doing an assignment in school and although I've checked through the entire written material I cannot for the life of me find out how to do this. We are supposed to enter strings like "0123 B" and the B at the end of the string is suppose to represent bronze and then add ++ to the Bronze integer. Then print the number of medals.

My issue here is that I'm trying to take the final character from the string (B, S, or G) and then add to that, but the thing is, it's a String and not a character. So I can't use medal.charAt(5).

Here is my code below:

**EDITED, CODE IS SOLUTION**

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountMedals {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int bronze = 0;
        int silver = 0;
        int gold = 0;
        int totalMedals = 0;
        int incorrectMedals = 0;
        char gol = 'G';
        char sil = 'S';
        char bro = 'B';
        String medal = " ";

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the event number followed by the first letter of the medal type." +
                " (I.E. \"0111" + " B\"). Type exit once completed");
        while (!medal.equals("")) {
            medal = in.nextLine();
            if (medal.charAt(medal.length() - 1) == bro)
            {
                bronze++;
                totalMedals++;
            }
            else if (medal.charAt(medal.length() - 1) == sil)
            {
                silver++;
                totalMedals++;
            }
            else if (medal.charAt(medal.length() - 1) == gol)
            {
                gold++;
                totalMedals++;
            }
            else if (medal.equals("exit"))
            {
                System.out.println("Gold medals: " + gold);
                System.out.println("Silver medals: " + silver);
                System.out.println("Bronze medals: " + bronze);
                System.out.println("Total medals: " + totalMedals);
                System.out.println(incorrectMedals + " incorrect medal(s) entered.");
            }
                else{
                incorrectMedals++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just change the medals to be characters? It's only one letter anyways

Comment: We have to use the assigned input. They have assigned us to put in strings like "0123 B", "0124 S", "0532 G"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make `gol`, `sil`, and `bro` into `char`s instead of `String`s.

```
char gol = 'G';
char sil = 'S';
char bro = 'B';
```

After that change, you should be able to use

```
medal.charAt(5) == gol
```

no problem.

**Edit**

To make this even more generic, you could use

```
medal.charAt(medal.length() - 1) == gol
```

which will always pull the last character, thereby avoiding errors with input that has less than 5 indices.

Comment: Or you could make your life a hell miserable and try do do via a regex :)

Comment: I have done that and it doesn't seem to work.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
 at CountMedals.main(CountMedals.java:20)

Comment: I figured it would've been easier to split into two string arrays by the space and take the second one and evaluate it. But we haven't gone that far as it's only my third week in the course for Java.

Comment: @Kalian that means you're trying to read a character that's not in the string. Keep in mind, the letter is position-1 (stars at 0)

Comment: @Kylian That's an out of bounds exception. It means that whatever string it tried to pull from does not have an index 5. What string did you enter? "0123 B" should have 5 indexes.

Comment: @Kylian If you want to always get the last character, you can do `medal.charAt(medal.length - 1)`. That will always grab the last character in the string and will avoid errors where you enter something too short, like "22 B".

Comment: Oh, it happens when I'm trying to cancel it off and get the output. When I type "" and click enter is when the error arises. Is there a better way to type a way to make it cancel out and enter the input once I've entered the desired amount fo information?

Comment: @Kylian You have initiated String medal = " "; but in code you are equating it to while (!medal.equals("") . You have to keep it consistent and make it while (!medal.equals(" ")

Comment: @xCodeZone that's wrong... if he writes `while (!medal.equals(" "))` the loop will never run since the initial value is `" "`.

Comment: I made it " " sot hat you can add input, and I expected that when I enter "" that it would then evaluate to false and then the output would print. That was my way of ending the program once you enter all the input.

Comment: @Kylian It might be better to have an explicit exit condition, like when the user types "exit".

Comment: Is there a way I can message you directly just for this question? So we don't have to type here. I can't find a message button on StackExchange.

Comment: My I add that I do know a lot of Ruby & even JavaScript and it would have been insanely easier to do in either of those languages.. Java is hard.